# Visa API to support transaction from multiple card types

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway

I am looking forward to integrate VISA payments API(https://developer.visa.com) in my nodejs based website. 
In my scenario, there are two types of users, buyers and merchants meaning that any buyer can send amount to any merchant. For example, buyer1 buys a product from merchant1, so the buyer1 should be able to send the payment to merchant1, similarly, buyer2 buys a product from merchant2, so it should be able to send the payment to merchant2. In addition to that, I want to allow users to transfer payments from every types of switch(Master Card, American Express etc) to every type of switch(Master Card, American Express etc) like Master Card to American Express, American Express to Visa and so on.

Currently, I am using the Visa Direct API and I am able to make a pull request from only Visa cards, but push is working for every type of cards. But pulling from other cards is giving PAN error. Does it not allow to pull from other switches?

In that case what API should be used?

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Thank You.